# Changing certain values in a column using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

From the data that is imported, I want to replace all numbers with a specific letter(Make a new column based off that data). The thing is the data that is being imported has some cells with letters and some cells with numbers. I want to keep the cells that have letters with no change but change the cells that have numbers into letters.

I made a dictionary to make the change happen;

```
def get_value(value, dictionary):
    print(dictionary.values())

    if value in dictionary.values():
        answer = [k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v == value][0]
        # answer = answer[1]
    else:
        answer = "No data"

    return answer
```

```
Num_to_letter ={
    "F": "1",
    "G": "2",
    "H": "3",
    "J": "4",
    "K": "5",
    "M": "6",
    "N": "7",
    "Q": "8",
    "U": "9",
    "V": "10",
    "X": "11",
    "Z": "12"

}
df['New_column'] = df['Old_column'].apply(lambda x: get_value(x,Num_to_letter))
```

When the new column is produced I get 'No Data' for all cells that have a letter as well as 'No Data' for all cells that have a number unless its number is 10,11, or 12, those numbers are able to convert into a letter.

What is wrong with my code? Why am I getting 'No Data' besides double-digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you **Apply** a function on a column in a pandas dataframe, it'll apply to all cells of that column and return the value that the defined function has returned. You have returned in the `get_value` function either a letter or "No data". Since you said you want your letters unchanged, so you shouldn't return "No data" in your function; Rather, you should return the value itself. So, I suggest you change your code to what follows:

```py
def get_value(value, dictionary):
    if isinstance(value, str) and value.isnumeric():
      return dictionary[str(int(value))]
    else:
      return value

Num_to_letter ={
    "F": "1",
    "G": "2",
    "H": "3",
    "J": "4",
    "K": "5",
    "M": "6",
    "N": "7",
    "Q": "8",
    "U": "9",
    "V": "10",
    "X": "11",
    "Z": "12"

}
Num_to_letter_reverse = { Num_to_letter[k]:k for k in Num_to_letter}
df['New_column'] = df['Old_column'].apply(lambda x: get_value(x,Num_to_letter_reverse))
```

Comment: I get a Key error 03 when I do this

Comment: @Newbie Thanks for the comment. So you would need to change "03" to int first and then reformat it to a string. You can use the edited version of my answer now.